# What would be the safest method to power a laptop (IdeaPad 510 15isk) from a 14.8v battery pack?

Tags: safety, charger, protection, laptop, backup

Looking at my existing power jack and measuring it crudely with a cm ruler it *looks* like 3mm diameter x 1 cm length.  The laptop bottom and charging adapter both say 20v @ 3.25 A max. What would be the best way to deliver that power and have it remain smooth as the battery pack voltage drops from 16.8v to 11v (fully charged to dead)

It looks like a chinesium boost/buck module would be my best bet once I set the voltage via a multimeter and epoxy the adjustment knob so their is no way it could possibly get turned or rotate its self slowly due to thermal expansion or something.  I do not favor this idea though mostly because of the fact that most of those crappy boards look poorly put together and I highly doubt that the output is very well regulated and I fear that if one of those does break it may send to much or to little voltage to the laptop.

Are their any other options? If the boost/buck is my only option are their any safeguards I could use (besides a fuse ofc)?

Comment: The "best way" is use the proper AC adapter.

Comment: Despite your aversion to Chinese-made modules, most of them work just fine. As about 80% of other things in North-American households. You should worry more about over-discharging the battery.

Comment: Chinesium? Can't we be better than that?

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chinesium

Im sorry I did not mean to offend anyone chinese.  Chinesium refers to poorly made stuff which is usualt made in china.

Comment: @Andyaka well... yes it is the best way.  But unless you can plug an ac adapter into a tree its probably not going to be that functional outside.  Did you mean in conjunction with an inverter?  I considered that but that would require 3 different convertions (from battery to regulated 12v dc, then to 120v ac, then to 20v via charging adapter) and I imagine that all of those conversions would waste 40% of the power and be rather expensive.

Comment: Why do you say you need a buck boost module? The battery voltage is always below 20 V...

Comment: @VladimirCravero I actually only need boost but most of the modules I have seen have buck capability as well.

Comment: You didn’t state in your question that you didn’t have access to ac power. You may think this obvious given that you referred to battery power but given that a laptop has an internal battery and, to a lot of laptop users, an external battery pack is never a consideration, I think your question is weak in this respect.

Comment: As per your title, “the safest way” is to purchase a portable supply that is recommended by the laptop manufacturer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non isolated buck convertors powering something valuable, often had a crowbar circuit on the output. When over voltage occurs, the SCR is turned hard on, and stays on, until the fuse has blown. (if you use a triac it will also crowbar on reversed battery)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0cqCOm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the switch of a buck convertor fails, the input flows straight through the inductor to the output. If the load will be destroyed by this, then a crowbar (+fuse) is cheap insurance, and very simple to make.

For example my ebike battery has a usb 5V output, powered by 42V of lithium cells, and a shitty little buck convertor pcb. You bet I added a crowbar, cos I don't trust the regulator.

Transformer coupled power supplies don't have this issue as a fault generally results in no output. 
However most types of power supply are susceptible to the adjustment pot going open circuit, or being fiddled with. A hard crowbar remains cheap insurance if the load is valuable.

FYI, trimpots can fail where the wiper does not contact the track (permanently or momentarily due to shock). They should always be wired with 3 pins used, so that they don't go open circuit when this happens.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTjItH.png)</sup>

This is something to inspect and correct on cheap CN modules. You can always add fixed resistors to limit the max output voltage to something safe.

Comment: I will use [This](https://www.amazon.com/Converter-DROK-Non-isolated-Transformer-Regulator/dp/B076ZJX1YZ/ref=pd_sbs_328_7?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B076ZJX1YZ&pd_rd_r=93c6d9d8-9366-11e8-bdf3-a194229cc61a&pd_rd_w=RRR6Q&pd_rd_wg=6EFEz&pf_rd_i=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=8702255303818932494&pf_rd_r=K45TD2TFDB04SJ32P1HM&pf_rd_s=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_t=40701&psc=1&refRID=K45TD2TFDB04SJ32P1HM) module because it seems to offer the highest watt rating so since I will be using it at less than 1/3 of its max it should no suffer from over heating.   Problem is... im not bucking.

Comment: I need to boost 11-16.8v (4s li-ion) to arround 20v.  Is there a possibility of over voltage failure from boost modules?   If they fail in the same way as buck then it would send 14.8v to the output.

Comment: I will include a crowbar incase The knob gets adjusted or it fails in an unexpected way (probably user error).

Comment: Yes, the B-B convertor probably fails with the battery voltage out except for a trimpot fault. The proposed USB 5V output is a more typical case where you need it. If you get 16V on the USB plug, then you have an ex-iphone.

Comment: I cannot find a b-b converter rated for sufficient power.  Could I use a boost converter to bump it up to 29v and have a buck converter on its output to bring it back down to 20/24v?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be aware that several commercial solutions to your problem exist. The money involved seems around 100$ or something like that, and you get an object with its nice case, protections and such.

Yes, a DCDC module is the right choice here, as it allows to convert power with very high efficiency. If you fear a Chinese module is not well built simply buy a module from a manufacturer you trust. Be ready to pay it 10x the price of a Chinese module though.

You do not give much information about the battery, if it is a "raw" pack it should have a basic protection built in, but it is your task to properly charge it, possibly with another prebuilt module, and to make sure you do not overcharge or overdischarge the battery pack.

Comment: I am building a portable electronics work station which will have 100 watt hrs of li-ion cells, a power supply module, and a jack for a ts-100 soldering iron, and integrated soldering fume absorber.  I just recently thought that adding 5v usb out and a laptop charging option would be useful also.

Comment: So, it is not a battery pack for laptop only, as implied in your title, but a power supply module with multi-voltage outputs. Don't you think this information might affect the potential solutions?

Comment: Not really? The laptop powering system would use a totally different boost converter.  All of the power outputs will have a diode ensuring that no reverse current occurs. @Maple

Comment: @Maple any extra protection systems I should use in addition? Perhaps a large capacitor across the output to smooth the output power.

Comment: @5hutd0wnR35tart Sorry, I cannot give any reasonable advice without knowing what you are doing, and you keep changing that all the time. Come up with complete list of requirements, like all output voltages and maximum currents, how long you need battery to last, whether or not you want power output while battery is charging, built-in or external charger, what components you already have or planning to use etc. Then post another question and I am sure somebody will be able to help.

Comment: Ok I will make that post within 30 minutes.  I'm sorry, in a lot of other forums people get annoyed if you make posts on a lot of different questions in one post because it is less likely to help other people who may be reading in the future.