# How can I power mobile devices from my 36v or 48v battery safely?

Tags: batteries, usb, battery-operated

I want to buy a rear rack battery for my bike, but not for powering the bike. Instead, I want to power other things, such as an action camera+gimbal, a mobile phone charger, grip warmers, lights etc for a prolonged period of time. A simple USB power bank (or several) is insufficient.

The battery typically outputs 36 or 48v and what I need is typically but not always 5V at 1 or 2 amps (depends on the device). I wouldn't mind using this battery to also power the front light which right now eats 36v directly. The speaker has a mains powered connection at 100-220v/300mA so I have no idea if it's possible to convert in this direction and if it's safe to do so.

What piece of hardware do I need to power USB ports? Also, how can I make sure that at no point in time the full 36/48v get fed into my devices... I assume I would need to put fuses somewhere?

Comment: Why not use a typical USB Powerbank?

Comment: Buying a battery consisting of very many cells to give you 36 V or 48 V just to step that down to 5 V sounds like a bad design decision. Simply don't.

Comment: A power bank is too small. I want to power several devices throughout the day. Most are 5v, some (e.g. loudspeaker) could eat more.

Comment: Seems like a voltage regulator might be what you need.  You say "typically but not always 5V".  Can you please expand?

Comment: There are 12v power banks used in pro video, etc.  For the 5v gear just get several smaller ones to use up in turn - this really is additive.  Also note that loudspeakers on a bike will get you ticketed in many places unless part of a permit-authorized parade.

Comment: Added further clarification

Comment: Your problem here is that you insist on doing everything the hard way instead of the normal way.  There are inconsiderately bright bike headlights that work on one or two lithium cells, since LEDs themselves are low voltage and it's not worth stringing that many dies together for this.  2 amps of current is well within what better USB power packs can do.   There are plenty of DC powered amps you can use to get yourself arrested for violating noise ordinances.  Fundamentally high voltage packs are for *motors* and long wiring runs, neither of which apply to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got dolphin (bottle) batteries specifically because they can be taken off the bike, and have a direct plug to use them as a giant power bank for laptops and battery drills. Mine is 36V 17.5Ah.  Stonking!

BTW, if you get the battery, then get the motor (TSDZ2 is what I got SWMBO, I've been using it this week - fantastic)

Decide if you are using 36V or 48V.  If you are going to use 48V, then you need a module that can handle 60V (because thats what a fully charged 48V pack can make). At 36V (42V charged) you have a bit more choice. I went with [this to run my battery drill](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/200W-15A-DC-DC-8-60V-48V-TO-1-36V-5V-12V-24V-19V-Buck-Converter/32831166619.html) from the ebike battery. Just arrived, and I haven't tested it yet.

At the 5V end you might want to add a fuse and "[crowbar](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/388310/107557)" circuit. I would. The crowbar short circuits the power when it goes high - say 7V. Note that crowbars are to give your expensive phone a chance of surviving - at the expense of the power supply and the crowbar itself. Your phone won't win a fight with 50 lithium batteries, *when* the cheap module fails.

A good approach is to use the switchmode to make 8V, then use a linear regulator (7805,LM317) to make 5V. This limits the current to the USB, and reduces noise. A 15A switchmode module is not exactly an appropriate current limit when something goes wrong at the usb end.

I have not found a small 36Vor48V->mains convertor yet. 24V ones do exist. Youcan still get small 24V ebike packs, which might be better for your goal (but a very poor choice for an ebike)

Answer (score 2):

There are many cheap and powerful  DC-DC converters on the market. You need step-down configuration. Try searching "buck converter".

However, be aware that some of them (especially cheap ones) may be really noisy. This noise may affect badly on electronics. Kinda cheap and dirty solution is to set up a voltage around 6-7V and then use voltage regulator with high PSRR to get clean 5V.

Also, if you are considering 48v getting into 5v, you may put a thermal fuse on regulator. In case of 48v regulator will get most of voltage and fuse will break.